# Synapse Notebook reference - Call Synapse notebook from another with parameters

Tags: python, azure-synapse

I have a synapse notebook with parameters .I am trying to call that notebook from another notebook. I am using %run command.

How should I pass the parameters from the base notebook to the one that is being called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use Python and follow the example shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/microsoft-spark-utilities?pivots=programming-language-python&WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-4020762)?

```
 mssparkutils.notebook.run("folder/Sample1", 90, {"input": 20 })
```

Comment: How do you refer to root folder when the caller notebook is in subfolder? E.g. target notebook is `\\sharedLibrary`, caller notebook is `\\solution1\step1`. I couldn't find any functional syntax. Moving the library to solution folder was the only option (i.e. no problem calling it from `\\solution1\sharedLibrary` as `%run '/solution1/sharedLibrary`

Answer (score 5):

Also, for me the above answers didn't work.

As a separate solution to this, below is an answer.

> 1. Open the notebook and go to the properties tab on extreme right adjacent to 3 dots.
> 2. Check "Enable Unpublish Notebook reference."
> 3. Commit all changes.

Now, you will be able to use both `%run` and `mssparkutils` command.

Comment: How do you pass parameters?

Comment: @James For that you use: mssparkutils.notebook.run("folder/Sample1", 90, {"input": 20 }) as answered below.

Comment: yes this is what helped me to get it working. before doing the "Enable Unpublish Notebook reference" i was not able to invoke the notebook

Answer (score 1):

at this time you should first import an library

```
from notebookutils import mssparkutils

mssparkutils.notebook.run('yourfolder/yournotebook')
```