# notebook activity in ADF not able to call another synapse notebook

Tags: azure-data-factory, spark-notebook, azure-synapse-analytics, azure-synapse-pipeline

[Synapse Notebook reference - Call Synapse notebook from another with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68582804/synapse-notebook-reference-call-synapse-notebook-from-another-with-parameters/77195088#77195088)

notebook_name = '/NB_dim_load'

using

mssparkutils.notebook.run(notebook_name, 90, {"notebookparams": Job_configInfo_dicencoded})

the problem is when i ran my notebook from synapse notebook activity in ADF. but when i ran it notebook directly , able to call another notebook with encoded parameters ? CAN YOU HELP ME whats the solution?

Comment: Error: An error occurred while calling z:mssparkutils.notebook.run.
: com.microsoft.spark.notebook.msutils.NotebookExecutionException: Fetch notebook content for /NB_dim_load failed with exception: Request to fetchNotebookContent failed with status code 404 error {"message":"{\"code\":\"NotFound\",\"message\":\"The document could not be retrieved because it does not exist.\",\"target\":\"/subscriptions/........../providers/Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/......../notebooks/NB_dim_load\",\"details\":null,\"error\":null}"}..

Comment: I doubt the notebook name starts with a '/' - try referencing just "NB_dim_load"

Comment: @JoelCochran - I tried after removing the '/'. still the problem is there.  Need a help on this.

Comment: Are you using Git? If so, can you switch to Live and verify it shows the Notebook?

Comment: @JoelCochran - No, notebook not showing up in live mode.  
but I enabled unpublished notebook reference under notebook settings.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that setting, but it sounds like not being Published could be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly, Notebook name should start and end with letter, number or underscore (_).**

> Fetch notebook content for /NB_dim_load failed with exception: Request to fetchNotebookContent failed with status code 404 error {"message":"{"code":"NotFound","message":"The document could not be retrieved because it does not exist.

**The error you are facing is because of incorrect Notebook name or Inappropriate Notebook path.**

To resolve this, make sure you are using proper notebook path or notebook name and check **Enable unpublished notebook reference** on every notebook.

[image]

As you see in above pictures, I tried with notebook name similar to yours and it got succeeded.

[image]

Comment: from the beginning I Enabled unpublished notebook reference. if the issue relates to proper notebook path or notebook name, it could fail even when i ran notebook directly! isn't it.!

In my case mssparkutils.notebook.run(notebook_name, 90, {"notebookparams": Job_configInfo_dicencoded})
within the for loop

Comment: **just to clarify. its not in ADF, running Notebook from Synapse pipeline with a notebook activity.**

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/synapse-notebook-activity